# split function is not working in js

Tags: javascript

this code is showing error on line 4,i couldn't figure out why.

```
function checkImage(){
   var file1,exts,statusFile;
   file1=$('#image').val();
   var get_ext=file1.split(".");
   statusFile=$('#imageP');
   if($.inArray(get_ext,['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) != -1) {
     statusFile.html("");
   }
   else{
     statusFile.html("invalid extension!");
   }
}
```

it shows error that file1 is undefined on line 4

Comment: What is `$('#image')` show the html. most likely it is not an element that can return a `.val()`

Comment: It would help if we could see your HTML.

Comment: You are assigning the value of an element with an id of `image` to your variable. That value is undefined. Use for example the chrome developer tools to look up that element

Comment: you need to provide the value of file1

Answer (score 0):

Your `file1` variable is `undefined` because `$('#image').val();` returned `undefined`. This happened likely because there was no DOM node with the ID of `image` at the time of this JS's execution.

Answer (score -1):

`.val()` on an img tag (I suppose that #image is an img tag) does not retrieve the url of the image. The attributte "src" does.
Try something like this:

```
function checkImage(){
   var file1,exts,statusFile;
   file1=$('#image').attr("src");
   var get_ext=file1.split(".");
   statusFile=$('#imageP');
   if($.inArray(get_ext,['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) != -1) {
     statusFile.html("");
   }
   else{
     statusFile.html("invalid extension!");
   }
}
```

I'm assuming that #image exists and is an img tag. But it looks more probably that #image doesn't exists